# Websocket plugin for Jmeter - for WSS

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to use websocket plugin http://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter to test websocket requests. We are able to connect to ws connections but not able to do wss connections.

For example, when I try to hit `wss://echo.websocket.org` we are getting `Unknown source` error from jmeter-websocket plugin.

Could someone please suggest if any workaround to use this plugin for wss.
Do we need to do any more configurations?

Error:

```
[Execution Flow]
 - Opening new connection
 - Using response message pattern ""
 - Using disconnect pattern ""
 - Waiting for the server connection for 5000 MILLISECONDS
 - Cannot connect to the remote server

[Variables]
 - Message count: 0

[Problems]
 - Unexpected error: null
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.sendMessage(ServiceSocket.java:156)    JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:136)    org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The same request (`wss://echo.websocket.org`) is working fine from https://www.websocket.org/echo.html.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an NPE is occurring which might indicate a bug in the plugin.

You should report it there with more details although plugin does not seem to be updated since 2014.

You may want to look at an alternative and maintained JMeter plugin for websocket:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers

It is available through [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=doornbosch) plugin manager.